# Verify your download

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, installation, release-verification

Why does Bitcoin core wallet bitcoin-26.0-win64-setup file
does not match the signatures of the SHA256 binary hashes or
SHA256 hash signatures which i can download same side. I think i do it wrong, somebody help how to check. I know to show me the hash, but they are different.

Comment: Please provide more details. What steps you undertook, what value you get, etc..

Comment: I downloaded both files from https://bitcoincore.org/. bitcoin-26.0-win64-setup (1).exe then the corresponding SHA256SUMS and also SHA256SUMS .asc. According to the instructions, the checksum of both files should match, but it doesn't. I think I'm doing something wrong

Comment: It's not the checksums of the SHA256SUMS themselves which is important, but the checksums contained in the file. Did you follow the instructions at https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/ under "Windows verification instructions"?

Comment: I suspected something like that, how can I open this file quickly? I don't understand the description on the bitcoin page

Comment: Generally you don't need to open it, but you can just use a text editor if you want. Checksum verification tools (like `sha256sum` on Linux; no idea on Windows) can directly compare the computer checksum of files with those in the SHA256SUMS file.

Comment: OK thanks to all very much, i do now understand. windows is just the same was matching the sha256